# chartjs 2.9.4 Trying to make a fixed horizontal line

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm trying to create a fixed horizontal line in `chartjs` 2.9.4 but I can't seem to get it right. The intention is to show if a fixed value has been exceeded that will be represented by the horizontal line. It looks like I'm following correctly the documentation for this veriosn of `chartjs` but I'm just having issues with this. Appreciate for the help.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    .chartMenu {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 40px;
      background: #1A1A1A;
      color: rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
    }
    
    .chartMenu p {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .chartCard {
      width: 100vw;
      height: calc(100vh - 40px);
      background: rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2);
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .chartBox {
      width: 700px;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      border: solid 3px rgba(54, 162, 235, 1);
      background: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chartCard">
    <div class="chartBox">
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // setup 
    const data = {
      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };


    const horizontalLine = {
      id: 'horizontalLine',
      afterDatasetDraw(chart, args, options) {
        const {
          ctx,
          chartArea: {
            top,
            right,
            bottom,
            left,
            width,
            height
          },
          scales: {
            x,
            y
          }
        } = chart;
        ctx.save();

        ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
        ctx.strokeRect(left, y.getPixelForValue(12), width, 0);
        ctx.restore();
      }
    }



    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        },
        plugins: [horizontalLine]

      },
    };

    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes.

1. Config: `plugins` node is set in the `options` one in your code. Instead, it should be defined in the same level of `options, data and type` (see below).
2. Plugin: you are referring to the scales assuming that their IDs are `x` and `y`. In chartjs 2.x, the scales ids are not x and y (by default) but x/y-axis-0.
3. Plugin: chart area in chartjs version 2 doesn't have widht and height (they will come with version 3) therefore you should use `right` value to get the width.

EDIT: you could use also chartjs-plugin-annotation I guess.

```js
    // setup 
    const data = {
      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };


 const horizontalLine = {
   id: 'horizontalLine',
   afterDatasetDraw(chart, args, options){
      const {ctx, chartArea: {top, right, bottom, left},
      scales:{y} } = chart;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
      ctx.strokeRect(left, y.getPixelForValue(12), right - left, 0);
      ctx.restore();
   }
 }



    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data,
      plugins: [horizontalLine],
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
                id: 'y',
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        
      },
    };

    const myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```